# How to download current template

Tags: templates, joomla

We have to redo our joomla website, however we can't find our local customized template.

Is there any way to download the current used template? Or can I even use my ftp access to download the template folder, zip it and use that?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the backend, you can't download it. But using FTP, you can download the folder, zip it and install it again if you want. That should work most of time for the simpler templates. If it's a bundle with a framework and other stuff, then it will fail because there are more files in other places.

The folder is within the /templates/ directory and depends on the name of the template.